# Sort Metafields by key

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is this possible to sort metafield by its key.

I have metafields as below.

```
[
  'key' => 1,
  'namespace'=>'some_data',
  'value'=>'some_other_stuff',
  'value_type'=>'json'
]

[
  'key' => 2,
  'namespace'=>'some_data',
  'value'=>'some_other_stuff',
  'value_type'=>'json'
]
```

Now while displaying this metafields I want to sort them by key , key will always be integer number.

Is this possible ? as something like below

```
{% assign data = shop.metafields.some_data | sort: 'key' %}
```

Any other suggestion is also welcome.

Comment: I think sorting this way will do not work if it is possible, As I think Shopify will not allow us change key using API

Comment: Hi @Bhargav, you said you want to sort metafields by key, why would you need to change the key? And yes, you're right - Shopify doesn't allow you to change the key. It's possible only by deleting and re-creating the metafiled again with another one. Anyway, was my answer any helpful to you?

Comment: which data  i want to store can be re ordered so I need to update key number, which seems not possible. I might be thinking in wrong direction. 

other solution I have thought is that I should save data in the single metafield in json format and always update it when user re-order the items. 

but there is only 65k characters we can store in single metafield so we need to create another if there is big data and this number may increase so sorting always big data and put it in the multiple metafield might not be good idea.

Comment: what about storing keys' sort order in a separate metafield?

Comment: if I store json in metafield I will need to take care if the data size exists 60K characters then I need to create another metafiled.

when data is sorted json will  be created every time in 60k char bunch and updated / created  to metafields.

I dont know this is the right flow or not. Let me know your thoght.

All public apps in app store saves data in their database and load data using script tag that is why they can perform sorting easily. but I can not let store do Ajax Requests all time that can slow down my low configuration server.

Comment: can you use separate metafields to store your data, rather than using a single JSON metafield. Will 60K be enough for your entities? What I meant is that if you have 10 metafields (with different keys), then you can just create another simple metafield to just store keys' sort order i.e. `key4,key1,key3,key9,...`

Comment: Yes Exactly I wanted to say the same thing  and when sorting happen on the data I need to update all the metafields there might be 5 / 7 max , what do you think this is the convenient way ?

Comment: Why would you need updating all the metafields? You would only need to update one metafields, the one that stores sort order and consists of other metafields keys. There's no need to update the metafields that store the actual data, at least from my point of view

Comment: Actually I am planning to store level FAQs for store in the metafields , FAQs are may not be in the 100s, but may exceed the 60k characters , if user change the position of the one FAQ then for all the FAQs position will change

Comment: Sorry, I think there's a misunderstanding. Let's say you have the following metafields with you FAQs:
`key = faq1, value = Content for the FAQ 1`, `key = faq2, value = Content for the FAQ 2`, ..., `key = faqX, value = Content for the FAQ X`. Then you may have another metafield with key = `faq_sort_order` and value = `faq1,faqX,faq2`. When you change order - then just update metafield with the key `faq_sort_order` e.g. to `faq2,faq1,faqX`. So, again, if user changes the position, you just update this one metafiled `faq_sort_order`.

Comment: No I want to add all faqs in single metafield in json_string format, untill it's size exists. and if there are that much FAQs having more than 60k Characters. then only I will create 2nd metafield if all FAQs size exceeds 120k Characters then only  there will be 3rd one. 

now when user sort this FAQs each faq will have new position which will be saved in my local DB i will fetch them sort by position and push to appropriate met afield.

if there the total size of faqs are 90k then first metafield with about 60k and send with 30K,

Comment: If you're keen on your approach - then yes, you would need to re-save all metafields on every position change. I see this approach as too complex for metafields subsystem. You need to split the data to save it, then concatenate it in the theme template to show it. This might not be obvious to others and not worth it, IMO.

Comment: You mentioned before that you don't want to make AJAX request because of the low configuration server. If you return cached results - it should be an issue, isn't it? The FAQ page is not the most frequently changed and visited page. Also, if you're trying to organize FAQ page - why you just don't go with theme sections or pages/navigation as it's generally done?

Comment: it will going to be an automated process of adding FAQ from the app. and app will save these data on metafields and serve data from there. unlike other apps serving data from their server using AJAX and App Proxy

Comment: Unfortunately, I ran out of ideas, taking into account all the constraints :( Re-saving all the metafields on position change, as you mentioned above, seems the only option you left with.

Comment: key sara sara , with the current flow will think about it in the second sprint

Answer (score 2):

1. Keys cannot be integers, strings only, minimum of 3 characters. But you can still pass 100 which will be converted to "100" (string). So you can use either `"001", "002", "003", ...` or `"100", "101", "102", ...` sequence.
2. You don't actually need to sort them as by default Shopify sorts them ascending by key. Just loop through them in your template e.g.

   ```
   {%- for metafield in product.metafields.some_data -%}
   <p>
     Key: {{ metafield | first  }}<br> 
     Value: {{ metafield | last }}
   </p>
   {%- endfor -%}
   ```